# PyFlink SQL local test

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

So I have a simple aggregation job written in PyFlink SQL API. The job read data from AWS kinesis and output result to Kinesis.

I am curious if I can unit-test my pipeline with say pytest? I am guessing I need mock the source and sink with filesystem connector? but how can I create a local Flink session to run the job inside the pytest ? Do we have best practice recommendation here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at how the tests for PyFlink itself are implemented. It sets up various base classes for implementing table test cases;  [`PyFlinkStreamTableTestCase`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/f8172cdbbc27344896d961be4b0b9cdbf000b5cd/flink-python/pyflink/testing/test_case_utils.py#L172) might a good place to start. Using this it's possible to write tests like this one that I've copied from [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/f8172cdbbc27344896d961be4b0b9cdbf000b5cd/flink-python/pyflink/table/tests/test_sql.py#L39):

```py
    def test_sql_query(self):
        t_env = self.t_env
        source = t_env.from_elements([(1, "Hi", "Hello"), (2, "Hello", "Hello")], ["a", "b", "c"])
        field_names = ["a", "b", "c"]
        field_types = [DataTypes.BIGINT(), DataTypes.STRING(), DataTypes.STRING()]
        t_env.register_table_sink(
            "sinks",
            source_sink_utils.TestAppendSink(field_names, field_types))

        result = t_env.sql_query("select a + 1, b, c from %s" % source)
        result.execute_insert("sinks").wait()
        actual = source_sink_utils.results()

        expected = ['+I[2, Hi, Hello]', '+I[3, Hello, Hello]']
        self.assert_equals(actual, expected)
```

There are many more tests where that one came from.

Comment: I notice that the `pyflink.testing` module is not included in the `apache-flink` distribution: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-python/setup.py#L268-L283 Is there a better way to use these test case utilities other than to copy paste into each project you want to use them in?

Comment: It seems that `pyflink.testing` is now being included in the distribution!